# Custom HtmlHelper method that generates an <input type="range"> HtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, lambda

As far as I know there are no (extension) methods in the `HtmlHelper` class that can generate a HTML5 `input` element of type `range` so I am trying to implement my own by extending the `HtmlHelper` class:

```
public static class MvcHtmlHelper
{
    public static HtmlString RangeFor<TModel, TProperty>
    (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression,
                       htmlHelper.ViewData);
        //var min = (string)((ViewDataDictionary<TModel>)htmlAttributes)["min"];
        //var max = (string)((ViewDataDictionary<TModel>)htmlAttributes)["max"];
        //var value = (string)((ViewDataDictionary<TModel>)htmlAttributes)["value"];
        return Range(htmlHelper, min, max, value);
    }

    public static HtmlString Range(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string name, string min, string max, string value = "0")
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.Attributes["type"] = "range";
        builder.Attributes["name"] = name;
        builder.Attributes["min"] = min;
        builder.Attributes["max"] = max;
        builder.Attributes["value"] = value;
        return new HtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

I am trying to emulate the existing `TextBoxFor` extension method which allows callers to specify extra `htmlAttributes` via an anonymous object. However I am getting an `InvalidCastException` on the commented lines above.

Can anyone point me to the correct way of obtaining the values from the anonymous `htmlAttributes` object (similar to how `TextBoxFor` handles `htmlAttributes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputExtensions.TextBoxFor handles attributes the following way:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
  return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, (IDictionary<string, object>) HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

So you have to create attributes dictionary from anomymous object before you use it